# How to recognize head movement in open CV?

Tags: python, opencv, spyder, haar-classifier

Good afternoon, I currently have some code which detects eyes and faces using haar cascades, I was curious to see if anybody knows how to get the program to recognize movement of the head e..g. nod or movement of the eye e.g. blink.

Here is what i currently have:

```
   import cv2
import numpy as np
"""
Created on Mon Mar 2 11:38:49 2020

@author: bradl
"""
# Open Camera
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
camera.set(10, 200)

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascades/face.xml')
##smile = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascades/smile.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascades/eye.xml')

while True:
    ret, img = camera.read()
    ## converts to gray
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ## determines what a face is and how it is found
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        ## Determines the starting and ending co-ordinates for a blue rectangle to be drawn around the face
        cv2.rectangle (img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255,0,0), 2)
        ## Declares the region of the image where the eyes will be 
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        ## Determines what an eye is based on the eye haar cascade xml file
        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
        for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes: 
            ##Draws green rectangles around the co-ordintates for eyes 
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (ex, ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh), (0,255,0),2)

    ##Displays camera        
    cv2.imshow('Image',img)
    ##Requires the user to press escape to exit the program
    k = cv2.waitKey(40) 
    if k == 27: 
            break
```

Does anybody have any ideas to get the program to recognize head or eye movement?

Comment: Hi, the code works and detects faces and eyes perfectly, I am just struggling to think of how to add a movement feature e.g. if you blink the program can detect it and maybe print the words "blink detected" to screen

Comment: optical flow for moving head up, down or any motion.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to detect eye blinking.

- In the ROI of the eyes apply white color detection.
- Draw contours of around this mask, if the area of the contour is above a threshold you can interpret the eye is open, whenever there is a sudden change in the area of the contour, that is the point of a blink.
  This method would fail if you move towards and away from the camera.

Another way of doing this would be face landmark detection using a library like DLIB.

Comment: I have this so far but it doesn't work correctly it says the eyes are always closed?        
                if eyes == (255,255,255): 
                cv2.putText(img,"Eyes open", (50,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, 2)
            else: cv2.putText(img,"Eyes closed", (50,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, 2)

Comment: eyes==(255,255,255) will not work. You need to perform thresholding first. After that, you need to draw contours and then calculate the area of the contour. If the area is above a threshold, then that means the eyes are open, else closed.